# How to name the logs from tflearn

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

How to create named logs when running Tensorflow with tflearn?

Every time it runs it creates a new log in TensorBoard.

```
model.fit(X, Y, n_epoch=100, snapshot_epoch=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the way by adding this parameter run_id to the fit method.

```
    model.fit(X, Y, n_epoch=100, snapshot_epoch=False, run_id='LOG_NAME')
```